# Finite sets with density

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For every $a\in(0,1]$ (and every $\epsilon>0$) there exists a number $M\geq 1$ such that whenever $X$ is a finite set and $A_1, \dots, A_M \subset X$ are subsets with $\frac{\# A_1}{\# X}, \dots, \frac{\# A_M}{\# X}>a$, then there exist $i,j \in \{1,\dots ,M\}$ such that $i\neq j$ and
$$
\frac{\# A_i \cap A_j}{\# X}>a^2 (-\epsilon)
$$

I am not sure if the epsilon should be there or not. That's why I put it in (). Does anyone have an idea how to prove this. Thanks!

Comment: @julien I think it is meant either $a^2-\varepsilon$ or $a^2$, depending on whether "(and every $\varepsilon>0$)" holds or not...

Comment: No, I don't mean $a^2 $ times $-\epsilon$.  I mean the whole statement should either be without epsilons or it should be $a^2-\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

By the *inclusion/exclusion* principle you have:
$$
  \# \bigcup_i A_i \ge \sum_i \# A_i - \sum_{i<j} \#(A_i\cap A_j)
$$
hence
$$
\# X \ge \# \bigcup_i A_i \ge M a\#X - \sum_{i<j} \#(A_i\cap A_j).
$$
Since
$$
\sum_{i<j} \#(A_i\cap A_j) \le \frac{M^2-M}{2} \max_{i<j}\#(A_i\cap A_j)
$$
we have
$$
\max \#(A_i\cap A_j) \ge \frac{Ma\#X - \#X}{\frac{M^2-M}{2}}
$$
So there exists $i$ and $j$ such that
$$
   \frac{\#(A_i\cap A_j)}{\# X} \ge \frac{2(Ma - 1)}{M^2-M} = \frac{2a}{M-1}- \frac{1}{M^2-M}\ge \frac{2a}{M-1} - \frac{1}{(M-1)^2}.
$$
If we take $M=2/a+1$ we get
$$
\frac{\#(A_i\cap A_j)}{\# X} \ge a^2 - a^2/4 = \frac 3 4 a^2. 
$$

Don't know if a better result can be achieved.

Comment: I don't understand how at least $\alpha \# X$ elements of $X$ belong to at least two sets $A_i$. What if M is big enough such that $\alpha =1$. Then you are saying all elements of $X$ belong to at least two sets $A_i$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm sorry but there are many things wrong with this proof. For instance I don't see that the "equally distributed among all pairs" case is the worst case, i.e. is any easier than the not equally distributed case. Also $\frac{2a}{M-1} - \frac{1}{M^2-M} > a^2 -\epsilon$ is not true if $M$ is allowed to be arbitrarily big. To clarify: We first fix $\epsilon$ and then we want to find $M$, not the other way around.

Comment: I made the proof some more precise.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get the last part. $M^2-M > \epsilon$ seems to be an unnecessary condition, since we think of $\epsilon$ to be close to zero and $M$ to be bigger than 2. Also how is $\frac{2a}{M-1} - \frac{1}{M^2-M} > a^2-\epsilon$ for big $M$? Note that no lower bound bigger than $a^2$ will do, so this is somehow a sharp estimate and needs more subtle reasoning than inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but it is still wrong. Do you maybe mean $M< \frac{2}{a}-1$ instead of  $M> \frac{2}{a}-1$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm not able to reach a^2...